# linear-gradient not working in Angular 8 with scss

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

here is my scss code:

```css
.banner {
  height: 170px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue); //not work
//   background-color: red; // <-this works 
}
```

I don't know why, I copied the linear-gradient code from MDN, it should not wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems not to be a problem of Scss but of css
remove the `-color`, its just `background`
`background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);`